# web api action not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

we have our main api in controller which takes two argument, but the issue is even we send these arguments to the api path, there is an error saying ""
No action or method matched". So we are confused how to make success call to our main api which returns the data in response object.

```
    RestService.BaseUrl = baseUrl;

    var client = RestService.Instance;

    var request = RestService.GetRestRequest("Payment/SyncWithIrd", 
    Method.POST);


    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    request.AddHeader("application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bmodel), ParameterType.RequestBody);

    request.AddHeader("application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mode)`enter code here`, 
    parameterType.RequestBody);

    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");

    var response = client.Execute(request);
    var value = response.Content;
    return value;
```

Comment: Please can you review the information at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and re-phrase/reask your question?

Comment: Thank you!! we have edited our questions properly.

Comment: Include the code (of the method) of the controller.

Comment: [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage SyncWithIrd(BillViewModel model,string mode) 
        {
            var result = _servicePayment.Sync_Ird(model, mode);
            if (result == "success")
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else 
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }

Comment: this method was not not found in the PaymentController when it is called  via var response = client.Execute(request); Please suggest us.

Comment: Please reply as this issue is till not resolved in our end

Comment: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI http://localhost:8072/api/user/SyncWithIrd. No Action was found on the controller "User" that matches the name "SyncWithIrd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some AddHeader in your code but no one AddBody. usualy verb Post have body part. Try to add [FromBody] at method signature like

```
[HttpPost] 
public HttpResponseMessage SyncWithIrd([FromBody]BillViewModel model, [FromBody]string mode)
```

Then remove

```
request.AddHeader("application/json; charset=utf-8", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bmodel), ParameterType.RequestBody);

request.AddHeader("application/json; charset=utf-8", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mode)`enter code here`,  parameterType.RequestBody);
```

Then Add instead AddHeader

```
request.AddBody(new { model = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bmodel) }, new { mode = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mode) });
```

ps. always use body part when call post verb.

Edited..

Put the parameter "string mode" of SyncWithIrd inside of BillViewModel and reconstruct your method signature like:

```
[HttpPost] 
public HttpResponseMessage SyncWithIrd([FromBody]BillViewModel model)
```

Then AddBody must be

```
request.AddBody(new { model = bmodel } });
```

ps. i use a similar code like this:

```
var restClient = new RestClient(model.ApiUrl);
var restRequest = new RestRequest("api/auth/createuser", Method.POST);
restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
restRequest.AddBody(new {
                            FullName = model.FullName,
                            Email = model.Email,
                            Username = model.UserName,
                            Password = model.Password
                        });
var restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

I hope its help. lmk

Comment: After we edit the code as per your suggestions, there were two errors came from the last line: request.AddBody(new { model = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bmodel) }, new { mode = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mode) });

Comment: The best overloaded method match for RestSharp.restRequest.AddBody(object, string ) has some invalid arguments

Comment: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'string'

Comment: Please suggest Ermindo

Comment: we are using http://restsharp.org/

Comment: Thanks, I will let you know.

Comment: ok your edited answers worked. Now we have to remove string mode after we received that in endpoint. How can we do that? It is necessary because we donot want to send/post mode in 3 rd party api.

Comment: Please suggest us.

Comment: after we use this, we have some other issue again

Comment: we get null model values in our API. please suggest what to do with that.

Comment: we did not get data in out post endpoint method:

Comment: [HttpPost] 
public HttpResponseMessage SyncWithIrd([FromBody]BillViewModel model)

Comment: please suggest what could we do inorder to get data in this method.

Comment: Ok we have got the endpoint by using above method, appending mode and sending each params in request body. Thank you for your wonderful help! :)